# Where can I find Microsoft assemblies that are not already in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, assemblies, gac, adfs

I figured someone can answer the question generally but if anyone wants to get specific I am trying to use:

using System.Web.Security.SingleSignOn;
using System.Web.Security.SingleSignOn.Authorization;

I've googled my brains out and this is the closest answer I found:

"We discussed this offline, but it looks like the ADFS assembly is GACed, but
not installed on the file system or registered with VS.NET so that it shows
up in the .NET tab. I'm guessing MS may need to beef up the installer for
this scenario. In the meantime, you probably need to do this yourself."

What on earth, do WHAT myself?

Comment: I have no idea what your question is. Why don't you try refining your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an [install log](http://web2.minasi.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=23116) showing that it was expected to be in

> C:\WINDOWS\ADFS\System.Web.Security.SingleSignon.dll

on Windows Server 2003. You probably need to have active directory installed for it to appear there because I checked one of my 2003 servers without AD and it wasn't there.

Normally I would guess the DLL would be registered in the system-wide Global Assembly Cache (GAC), so you wouldn't have to know the actual path for it. If an assembly is registered in the GAC, then you can add a reference to it by bringing up the "Add Reference" dialog and clicking on the ".NET" Tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the specified namespace in this file: *system.web.security.singlesignon.claimtransforms.dll*

But this file isn't normaly available but only installed in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache). You may find it under e.g. *c:\window\assembly...* and copy the dll to another path. Then you can manual reference it within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For projects using specific environment (like SharePoint object model)is recommended using virtual pc with installed in GAC assemblies. ADFS assemblies should have only Win server. If you find them and install manually in work environment (desktop) some possibilities (like debugging) will not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add the assembly to the ".NET" tab in the Visual Studio "Add References" dialog box, there's a registry setting you need to make. [KB30149 explains it in greater detail.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306149) The short version: You need to add an entry to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders` registry key.

If you're trying to locate a physical file corresponding to an assembly in the GAC, drop to a command prompt and go to `%WINDIR%\Assembly` (e.g., `C:\WINDOWS\Assembly`). Navigate around in there - that's where GAC'd assemblies live.