# Finding the assemblies required to develop ADFS custom claim transformation modules?

Tags: c#, adfs2.0

I want to build a custom claim transformation module as per [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736228%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Step 1 and 2 in that article: add references to the `System.Web.Security.SingleSignOn.ClaimTransforms.dll` and `System.Web.Security.SingleSignOn.Authorization.dll` assemblies.

I am unable to find these assemblies. I installed WIF and the WIF sdk on my Windows 7 laptop. After that, as per [this discussion](http://forums.asp.net/t/1764078.aspx/1/10?p=True&t=634636916631894310), I installed ADFS on a Windows 2008 R2 server. However, I could not find the assemblies there either, even when browsing the GAC from a command prompt.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction to locate these assemblies? There does not appear to be an ADFS sdk.

Comment: Similar question was asked here, do you have AD installed on the Windows 2008 R2 server that ADFS is set up on? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103178/where-can-i-find-microsoft-assemblies-that-are-not-already-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 3):

OK, got it. Merely installing the ADFS 2.0 download is not enough. The assemblies can be located in c:\windows\adfs\bin\ref, but only *after* the ADFS server role is enabled on the server. In my case, I had to follow these steps:

- install the AD role
- Activate the domain by running dcpromo.exe
- Install the ADFS role

After doing that, the required assemblies were in the folder mentioned in the other question. Both copying the assemblies to my win7 dev machine and running VS2010 on the (dev) W2K8r2 environment works now.

Comment: For me (ADFS 2.1, Windows Server 2012) C:\Windows\WinSxS\msil_system.web.security.singlesignon_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_7623a98e466702be

Answer (score 0):

The sample claimapp is written for ADFS come with windows 2008/(and R2). It's not for ADFS2.0 as one comment in MS page stated. The stock ADFS is enabled as a role, while ADFS2.0 is a separate installation - they use different method(paths) to find assembly modules. ADFS2.0 can work by its own - it doesn't need ADFS role added.